# React: TypeError: Cannot read property 'state' of undefined. Explanation required

Tags: reactjs, state, this, typeerror, react-functional-component

I'm just getting started with React and I run into this little TypeError: Cannot read property 'state' of undefined and I believe it's a basic JS stuff. Can someone explain please why I keep getting this error with a normal function syntax but not with an arrow function syntax. Here's the code that I wrote:

```
class App extends React.Component {
  state = {term: ''};

  onFormSubmit(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log(this.state.term)
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="ui segment">
        <form onSubmit={this.onFormSubmit} className="ui form">
          <div className="field">
            <label>Image Search</label>
            <input
              type="text"
              placeholder="Search"
              value={this.state.term}
              onChange={e => this.setState({ term:e.target.value })}
            />
          </div>
        </form>
        <h1 className="ui segment">{this.state.term}</h1>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

A little help would be appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 ways for functions inside a class Component to work with `this`

First one is to `bind` them inside `constructor`

```
 constructor() {
    super();
    this.onFormSubmit= this.onFormSubmit.bind(this);
  }
```

Second is by using this approach

```
  onFormSubmit = e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log(this.state.term)
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

You're using a class component so you need a constructor ([documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html)) like this

```
class Example extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      term: ''
    };
    this.onFormSubmit= this.onFormSubmit.bind(this);
  }
}
```

The [super](https://www.w3schools.com/Jsref/jsref_class_super.asp) keyword refers to the parent class.

It is used to call the constructor of the parent class and to access the parent's properties and methods, which is obviously what you want to do.

> When the event occurs and the handler is invoked, the `this` value falls back to default binding and is set to `undefined`, as class declarations and prototype methods run in strict mode.
> When we bind the `this` of the event handler to the component instance in the constructor, we can pass it as a callback without worrying about it losing its context.
> [Read more](http://freecodecamp.org/news/this-is-why-we-need-to-bind-event-handlers-in-class-components-in-react-f7ea1a6f93eb/)

Then, if you want to use regular function, you need bind `this` of that function with the class you've declared.

At this point you can start writing your function:

```
  onFormSubmit(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log(this.state.term)
  }
```

Another way around this is to use arrow function:

```
  const onFormSubmit = e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log(this.state.term)
  }
```

Alternatively, you can use function components. The reason why arrow function works is because it doesn't create its [own `this`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions). So, this in `onFormSubmit` is referring to the class `Example` rather than itself, which is clearly undefined ([Read more](https://kit-ko.medium.com/arrow-function-can-be-an-alternative-to-bind-in-javascript-51959a34e0ba)).

Comment: no need for constructor regarding the `state`. he can define `state` like this too.

Answer (score 0):

Suggestion:- use function components

There are 2 ways to fix this problem

Change :-

```
<form onSubmit={this.onFormSubmit} className="ui form">
```

to

```
<form onSubmit={(e) => this.onFormSubmit(e)} className="ui form">
```

OR

Change :-

```
onFormSubmit(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log(this.state.term);
  };
```

to

```
const onFormSubmit = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        console.log(this.state.term);
      };
```

Comment: the first way you wrote is not wrong. he doesnt have to change anything there